# Get element name from child class

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

When generating an XML from this code:

```
internal class Program
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

      using (StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\tomas\Documents\foo.xml", false))
      {
        var myFoo = new Foo();
        myFoo.Bar = new BarChildOne();

        XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo));
        mySerializer.Serialize(myWriter, myFoo);
      }
    }
  }

  public class Foo
  {
    public BarBase Bar { get; set; }
  }

  [XmlInclude(typeof(BarChildOne))]
  [XmlInclude(typeof(BarChildTwo))]
  public abstract class BarBase
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
  }

  [XmlRoot(ElementName = "BarChildOne")]
  public class BarChildOne : BarBase
  {
    public BarChildOne()
    {
      this.Name = "BarChildOne";
    }
  }

  [XmlRoot(ElementName = "BarChildTwo")]
  public class BarChildTwo : BarBase
  {
    public BarChildTwo()
    {
      this.Name = "BarChildTwo";
    }
  }
```

An XML like this is created:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Foo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Bar xsi:type="BarChildOne">
    <Name>BarChildOne</Name>
  </Bar>
</Foo>
```

However, I want the element name to be **BarChildOne**, as defined **by** in the child class, and not **Bar**.

Current: `<Bar xsi:type="BarChildOne">`
Expected: `<BarChildOne>`

If the derived class is `BarChildTwo` then the expected name is `<BarChildTwo>`.

Is this possible with the built-in XML serializer?

Answer (score 0):

Update the Variable name inside Foo:

```
public class Foo
{
    public BarBase BarChildOne { get; set; }
}
```

and update the referenced variable's name inside the serialization:

```
using (StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\temp\foo.xml", false))
{
    var myFoo = new Foo();
    myFoo.BarChildOne/**/ = new BarChildOne();

    XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo));
    mySerializer.Serialize(myWriter, myFoo);
}
```

yields the requested result:

> I want the element name to be BarChildOne, as defined in the child class, and not Bar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Foo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <BarChildOne xsi:type="BarChildOne">
    <Name>BarChildOne</Name>
  </BarChildOne>
</Foo>
```

Comment: That only changes the name in BarBase and does not inherit the name from the derived class. What about BarChildTwo?

Comment: You should edit your question if its intent is different than previously stated.